# making a javascript function/button click event call on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I need to invoke a javascript function (contains a jquery.ajax() call) like showfilterresult(). This call is invoked on a page monitoring.gsp onclick of a button like "filter".

The call I am making is from a different page, What I need to do is load the montoring.gsp page and also have this showfilterresult() call be made on the loaded page. (so I want to make 2 calls, one to the page and another to a function on the page)

Right now I am doing this:

```
 <javascript>
jQuery.ajax({
     var myurl = /myapp/users/monitoring
        url: myurl,
        dataType: 'html',
        timeout: 10000,
        beforeSend: function() {
             jQuery('#mydiv').html(../showspinner.gif)
          },
        success: function(data) {
        window.location = myurl;
        }
      });

</javascript>
```

The `showfilterresult()` function is as follows:

```
function showFilterResult(){
    var frm=jQuery('#fromDate').val();
    var to=jQuery('#toDate').val();
    if($('#fromDate').val().length>0  && $('#toDate').val().length>0){
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:{
                    'timeWindow':$("#timeWindow").val(),
                    'p1':p1,
                    'p3':$('#p3 option:selected').text(),
                    'fromDate':$("#fromDate").val(),
                    'toDate':$("#toDate").val(),
                },
                url: '/myapp/users/filterResult',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    jQuery("#filteredResult").html('/showspinner.gif')
                },
                success:function(data,textStatus){
                    jQuery("#filteredResult").html(data)
                }
            });
```

I also need to know How would I pass the url parameters to the showfilterresult() call from my page, by default the function takes the values from the textfields on the monitoring.gsp page.

Update: This is analogous to: I have my personal webpage and I need to invoke another webpage like google.com and also need to pass some parameters and invoke the "search" call on google.com with the parameters, so once I click link/button my webpage it not only forwards to google.com but also invokes the search event with my passed params and I directly see the google search results page.

Regards,
Priyank

Comment: Is this the actual Javascript code? If so, a construct like `jQuery.ajax({ var myurl = /myapp/users/monitoring … })` should in **any** case throw a JS error.

Comment: not the actual url...I have changed the url

Comment: That's not what I meant :) — Try http://jslint.com/ to check your code and fix the issues. As a pointer: JS objects in this notation can only hold `key:value` pairs like this `{ key1: "value1", key2: "value2", … }` — nothing else, no `var`, `=` or `;` unless it's in an anonymous function for a value.

Comment: Hi, This is an existing function working fine, so I dont want to correct it for now, its in an external .js file, thing I need to know is like I can call the page which has a call to this function and also call this function by passing (something like)  filter.clicked() since this function is called on filter button click, I need to know how do I pass the parameters which I have in my current page to this function?

Comment: This might not be the best approach, but make your first ajax call to an action in a controller and in that action render the template _montoring.gsp with modal values that you want for example set a flag to true and on _monitoring.gsp on the load event check that value and respond accordingly.

Comment: do you mean that I have to add a condition/flag to the event which fires showfilterresult() in monitoring.gsp? How do I render the template with "modal values" . Sorry could not understand that part.

Comment: also how how do I pass all the parameters that I have in my js function to _monitoring.gsp which are required by the showfilterresult() function on that page (p1,p2,p3 etc)- its currently taking these values from the textfields on _montoring.gsp as you see..

Comment: Thanks for your help.., I am using the flag to call the search on the loaded page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use native `jQuery.ajax` function. In grails you have a `jquery` plugin.

1. Install this plugin using `grails install-plugin jquery`.
2. Import the jQuery files into your html using `<g:javascript library="jquery" />`
3. Replace your first AJAX function with:

   ```
   <g:remoteFunction
        controller="user"
        action="monitoring"
        before="$('#mydiv').html('../showspinner.gif')"
        onComplete="window.location = ${createLink(
            controller: 'user', 
            action: 'monitoring')}" />
   ```
4. Replace your second AJAX function with:

   ```
   <g:remoteFunction
        controller="user"
        action="filterResult"
        params="$('#yourFormId').serialize()"
        before="$('#filteredResult').html('/showspinner.gif')"
        update="filteredResult" />
   ```

Maybe you have to check, whether your params are set correctly. In any case you can provide parameters in the first case by using `params` tag.

Comment: yeah its good syntax change, I donot use forms in my page where I am calling from, since I get all values from another source. Also the second function which you have shown is to be invoked on pageload of first function I cannot call it seperatley since the 'filteredresult' div is part of monitoring.gsp page.

Comment: Do Not make Ajax Calls on page load. Render the stuff you need directly into the response. Therefore use the update Tag instead of changing URL manually.

Comment: I am finally able to do what I want.. I am passing my parameters in first call to monitoring action, Setting the text fields on the resulting page from these parameters using hidden fields so that the textfields are all populated and then invoking the search event automatically on the populated page by passing a hidden flag and checking it on pageload of the resulting page.....all in 1 click! Thanks for the tips!